# cocos2d, Splitting an image into serpate R B G channels?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I want to create an effect where after my character gets killed, the red, blue, green color channels of the characters sprite separate into different directions.

something similar to this > http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/create-a-retro-crt-distortion-effect-using-rgb-shifting/

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add different offsets when looking up the individual colors in the fragment shader. To make this efficient you should probably render to an intermediate buffer first.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
vec4 mainOld( vec2 offset ) {

    ... (gl_FragCoord.xy + offset) ...
}

void main( void ) {
    vec4 foo;
    foo.r = mainOld(vec2(-3.0, 0.0)).r;
    foo.g = mainOld(vec2(0.0, 5.0)).g;
    foo.b = mainOld(vec2(0.0, 0.0)).b;
    foo.a = mainOld(vec2(0.0, 0.0)).a;
    gl_FragColor = foo;
}
```

Basically the original shader is now called three times so that's a bit inefficient, which is why I suggested a buffer but that may be premature optimization.

You can look at the result of the above code in an actual shader here:
http://glsl.heroku.com/e#7971.0 (not sure how persistent these links are, sorry)

Comment: Hey Sarien, the Character has an animation when he dies. I want to be able to continuously do the effect while animating the death. Is it still efficent to render to an intermediate buffer first? or is that only best if I have a Constant Sprite for the character.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. In many cases no buffer will be necessary.